# Find IP stream URL from webpage widget

Tags: stream, ip, feed, rtsp

I am looking for IP url's from a website. They are some simple beach IP cams, I would like to use them in an app. However, I can't extract the IP url using Google developer tools.

This is the website: 
https://www.middelkerke.be/nl/toerisme/webcams

Using developer tools, I can see these two streams that look like this:

https://ipcamlive.com/player/player.php?alias=middelkerke&%3Bautoplay=0&%3Bmute=1

And the other streams looks the same, also using the ipcamliveplayer.

But I can't use this in VLC for example. Does anybody have an idea? It's for my mom, she likes to see this specific beach.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know port number that IP cams? 
I think that IP cams have username - password.

IP cam live's IP address is 84.22.111.194 and I try default rtsp port ( 554). But it didn't work.

Namely, first of all, you can learn that camera router IP address and camera port. And then If is there any username - password you can't stream that video.

I advice you, contact that site owner and ask him "IP address, port number and username-password" after that you can create your RTSP command line."

I hope that answer can help you.

Comment: Thanks, just send the mail!